# How do you prove that polynomial reductions are not symmetric?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

How would I go about showing that L $\leq_p$ L' does not necessarily imply L' $\leq_p$ L? I was thinking I should show an example of two problems, where one can reduce to the other but not the other way round, but am not sure what such problems could be.

Answer (score 4):

You have a good plan of approach.  Now you need to spend some more time pursuing this.  Try to come up with a list of languages $L$ you've seen before, and try different pairs to see if they satisfy the condition.  After some trial and error you should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: I was thinking something like SAT < HALT but not the other way round?

Comment: @JasmineGrosso, don't just guess -- try to prove your answer correct!  That's how you will know whether you are right or not.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this insight will be helpful (along with your own thoughts and D.W.'s answer):

Quite intuitively, the relation $A \le_p B$ indicates that $B$ is more "difficult" than $A$. Indeed, for an NP-hard problem, like SAT, we know that all other NP languages $A$ can be reduced to it, which makes it "the hardest".. But not all languages are NP-hard, some languages are "easier" than others..

Comment: I would go with a trivial set for A, no need to complicate things with bringing in SAT. ;)